# Difference between infinite and not defined for sec function

Tags: trigonometry

The statement $\sec^2(\theta)=\frac{4xy}{(x+y)^2}$ is true if:

a) $x+y\ne0$

b) $x=y, x\ne0$

c) $x=y$

d) $x\ne0, y=0$

Given the above question. I got to the point that for this to be true $x=y$ but I think that they shouldn't both be zero because if we do that, then the Denominator of Right hand side becomes $0$ (not tending to $0$ but $0$) so the right side would become not defined (not $\pm\infty$) but not defined. Which would not be a possible output of $\sec$. So the answer according to me, should be (b) but the answer given is (c)

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Please use this next time: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I don't think you're going wrong at all.  The expression $(4\cdot0\cdot0)/(0+0)^2$ is undefined.

Comment: @JohnDoe thanks a lot for beautifying my question. I'd learn from the link :)

Comment: @BarryCipra could you please write an answer? Explaining which answer is right and why

Answer (score 2):

The OP's reasoning seems spot on to me.  In particular, when setting $x=y=0$, the expression $4xy/(x+y)^2$ is of the form $0/0$, which is undefined.  So answer (b) looks correct to me.

Answer (score 0):

$\sec^2 \theta \ge 1$ for all $\theta$ at which $\sec\theta$ is defined.

$\frac{4xy}{(x+y)^2} \ge 1$

$4xy \ge (x+y)^2$

$4xy \ge x^2 + 2xy + y^2$

$0 \ge x² - 2xy + y²$

$0 \ge (x-y)^2$

Since the square of any real value is non negative, the only case in which this expression can be true is the case of $(x-y)^2 = 0$. Therefore given expression can be true only for $x = y$.

And if x and y equals to 0. Then both sides are not equal. So I think (b) is correct.

Comment: This doesn't really address the OP's question, which concerns the fact that when you substitute $x=y=0$ into $(4xy)/(x+y)^2$, you get $0/0$, which is not defined.

Comment: 0/0 is 0. Its not undefined.

Comment: If that were true (which it's not), then answer (b) would certainly be true, since the secant function is *never* equal to $0$.  You'd be contradicting your own answer!

Comment: I am skipping $sec^2\theta$ equal to 0. Now is it fine?

Comment: If you still think $0/0$ is $0$ instead of being undefined, then no.  To put the objection another way, if $0/0=0$, then calculus would collapse into nothingness, since one would then have $\Delta y/\Delta x\to0/0=0$ for all (continuous) functions $y(x)$....